# OpenLDAP failing to add new attributes

Tags: ldap, openldap

I want to create some user accounts with attributes like "gender", meaning I need to create custom attributes.

I have created the following LDIF file:

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0 NAME ( 'gender' ) DESC 'gender' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

and try to apply it with  `ldapmodify -D cn=admin,cn=config -W -f ExtendedUser.ldif`.

But I always get this error:

```
modifying entry "cn=schema"
ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: attributeTypes: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

I know that I also need an object class to use the attribute anyway, and I initially tried this with an object class definition and other attributes included (see below), but that caused the same error.

old, more elaborate LDIF:

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0 NAME 'gender' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.1 NAME 'birthdate' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.2 NAME 'birthplace' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.3 NAME 'nationality' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.4 NAME 'street' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.5 NAME 'zipcode' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.6 NAME 'city' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.7 NAME 'phone' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
attributeTypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.8 NAME 'matnr' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )

dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: objectClasses
objectClasses: ( 4.5.6.7.8.9.2 NAME 'AdditionalAttrPerson' DESC 'adds user attributes' SUP inetOrgPerson STRUCTURAL MUST ( gender $ birthdate $ birthplace $ nationality $ street $ zipcode $ city $ phone $ matnr ) )
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, as I've copied the syntax from tutorials and it seems to match. Please help.

I tried to ldapmodify with debug levels activated, the output doesn't seem useful but here is the tail end, with the error:

```
...
ldap_do_free_request: asked to free lr 0x561b24af5cb0 msgid 2 refcnt 0
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_msgfree
ldap_err2string
ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: attributeTypes: value #0 invalid per syntax

ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_send_unbind
ber_flush2: 7 bytes to sd 4
ldap_free_connection: actually freed
```

The stuff above it definitely doesn't seem related to me.

Comment: (a) I think you want `cn=config,cn=schema`, (b) you can't modify `cn=schema` itself, you would need to modify an existing subentry (e.g. `cn=config,cn=schema,cn=core.ldif`) or create a new subentry with your desired schema (`cn=config,cn=schema,cn=my-schema`).

Comment: @larsks There were more problems than just that, but you were right about this. Not sure about the order, I did cn=myschema,cn=schema,cn=config and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I should have just looked at the other LDIF files in schema to begin with, but here's my solution:

the first line needs to be `dn cn=myschema,cn=schema,cn=config`

and the ones after that should have olcAttributeTypes or olcObjectClasses on the left side, not what I had. Example:

```
dn: cn=myschema,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: myschema
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.995.1.2.1 NAME 'gender'
 EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{256} SINGLE-VALUE )
```